# powers of $f(x)$ where $f(x)\in\mathbb{Q} [x]\setminus\mathbb{Z} [x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, polynomials

Let $n\geq 2$ be an integer. If $f(x)\in\mathbb{Q} [x]\setminus\mathbb{Z} [x]$ can $f(x)^n$ be in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $k$ be the smallest positive integer such that $kf(x)$ has integer coefficients. Then $k\gt 1$ and $kf(x)$ is a primitive polynomial. By Gauss's Lemma, $(kf(x))^n$ is primitive. Thus $(f(x))^n$ cannot have integer coefficients.